# iFrame with DIV and Jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am trying to use content of other website into my website. I tried using DIV with Jquery instead of iframe tag `<iframe>`

My Codes :

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#divframe').load('http://www.example.com');     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divframe"></div>
</body>
```

it returning no value and not showing the content of the example.com on my website. means the page is empty & blank.

Edited: I am looking for iframe solution without `iframe`, `object`, `embed` tag.

Please help me to get it fixed :)

Comment: You can't do that because it violates the same-origin policy.

Comment: Also, the website will have its own `<head>` and `<body>` elements -- you can't nest those inside the body of your own web page.

Comment: @Barmar even i remove `<head>` and `<body>` tag, still the page display empty and blank.

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: Aren't you getting a CORS error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Barmar yes, your right. I am getting a error Cross-Origin Request Blocked like you said same-origin policy but i got these code from stackoverflow and lot of stackoverflow user mentioned it working.

Comment: It will work if you're loading from the same domain, or the remote domain explicitly allows CORS.

Comment: @Barmar i got your point. I understood now, thanks for the help. anyway do you have any alternative solution for it?. I do not want to use iframe, object or embed tag.

Comment: Sorry, but the whole idea of CORS is to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: you have to set iframe width and height. so that it would work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use iframe tag and [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to do this.

NOTE : you also need to be sure that the url of the website is not protected to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iframe like youtube.com, google.com, etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#divframe').attr("src", "https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="divframe" style="width:100%;height:95vh"></iframe>
```